# How can I assign an object's property to a variable ..,?

Tags: javascript

I have five variables each contain an editable div element .. I want to create an object with five properties then assign these properties to the innerText of the five variables ..

```js
let firstName = document.querySelector(".firstName").innerHTML
let secondName = document.querySelector(".secondName").innerHTML
let marsName = document.querySelector(".marsName").innerHTML
let email = document.querySelector(".phoneOrEmail").innerHTML
let password = document.querySelector(".password").innerHTML
let All_is_well = document.querySelector(".allIsWell");
All_is_well.addEventListener("click", () => {
let form = {
 firstName,
 secondName,
 marsName,
 email,
 password,
}
 fetch(
"http:localhost:5000/api/register",
{
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(form),
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  cache: 'no-cache'
}
)
.then(res.json())
.then((data) => {
  // Handle response
  console.log("Success: ", res);
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Handle error
  console.log("Error: ", error);
});

console.log(form);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="comment"> install your landed spaceship on mars </div>
  <div class="firstName"      contenteditable="true"  spellcheck="false"> </div>
  <div class="secondName"     contenteditable="true"  spellcheck="false"> </div>
  <div class="marsName"       contenteditable="true"  spellcheck="false"> </div>
  <div class="phoneOrEmail"   contenteditable="true"  spellcheck="false"> </div>
  <div class="password"       contenteditable="true"  spellcheck="false"> </div>
  <button type="submit" class="allIsWell"> All is Well </button>

</form>
```

when I print the object in the console, each property is assigned a value " ".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKskk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BME5D.png)

Comment: It's a good idea to stick to JS conventions: variables use lowerCamelCase for their names. so `firstName`, not `First_name`. Also, you can declare object properties as part of the object primitive, so `let form = { firstName: ..., secondName: ..., ...etc...}`. With that said: show the result of that console log in your post, as well as the relevant HTML in [mcve] form. Ideally: show your problem using a runnable snippet, since it's a plain html and js problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ..
Is that good enough ..,??

Comment: Sure, but what's the problem now? This code does exactly what it should: the content of your divs are a single space for each one of those divs, so when the JS runs (which is immediately), it shows those spaces. If you need it to run _after_ someone edits the content for the divs, make it does that (e.g. by intercepting the form submit, or listening to change events on the divs, etc).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ..
I tell you .. I added another photo please take a look at it ..
there's an error message that disappears quickly in the console .. I can't even read it ..
in addition .. my friend the backend tells me that nothing is sent to the database .. 
and I feel disappointed .. I don't know what's wrong .. I've consumed a lot of time trying to discover the problem .. and I have no time left ..

Comment: Don't add pictures of text, [put the text in your post](/help/how-to-ask). WIth that said: there are no errors in the images you're posting, that is literally what the code you wrote should do. There is _nothing wrong here_, the code works exactly as it should. The page loads, there are spaces in your divs, your JS runs, and it grabs those spaces and assigns them to your variables. If that's not what you want, [explain what you _want_ to achieve](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ..
I deleted the image and updated the code as you requested sir .. 
so, since the code is all good .. then what is the problem .. why don't the data be fetched to the api ..

Comment: you're _still_ getting the values _immediately_ on script load. Meaning they'll just be spaces. So: don't do that, get the values inside that click handler so that you get the values at the time that click happens.

Comment: will that work if I replaced the button element by a normal div and make it looks like the button using css .. so that by clicking it .. the form will not become empty .. and then the post will be success .. is that good ..,??

Comment: Look, at this point, you _really_ just need to take some time, find a good (and modern) HTML5 + JS (es6 or later) tutorial, and just learn how to do some basic things, because this is very much a basic thing: you want to get content, and you want to get that only once it's time to do something with that content.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ..
Sir .. I think I solved the part of the empty properties .. however .. it gives me a 405 error .. method is not allowed ..

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

I uploaded a photo of the error ..

Comment: Please remember that this is [not a general help forum](/help/on-topic). You are expected to write a clear and concise [question](/help/how-to-ask), and then Stackoverflow can (hopefully) provide a detailed answer and that is not happening here. You're updating your question, changing it, several times, and using the comment section as a debugging tool. That's not what this site is for, so: find a good tutorial, learn some HTML/JS (and modern JS, make sure it mentions ES6 or ES2016 or some later year), and then take it from there. Comments are not for iteratively solving problems.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ..

At least tell me what specifically should I learn .. cause it's really not the suitable time for relearning JS and HTML .. I promise I'll relearn them .. please sir ..

Comment: Now is the _best_ time to learn. You want to do something incredibly basic: (re)learn the basics, because your don't know them right now.

Answer (score 0):

Does your divs got the right classes ?

Please make sure you're saving values **after** editing the divs.

For example, by clicking on a "Save" button.

```js
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let first = document.querySelector(".element1").innerText;
  let second = document.querySelector(".element2").innerText;
  let third = document.querySelector(".element3").innerText;

  let props = {};

  props.first = first;
  props.second = second;
  props.third = third;

  console.log(props); // returns the right values for me
});
```

Comment: So should I add an event listener ..,??

Comment: @MohamedNasr Yes you should.
And if you want submit a form you can just get data at backend.

Comment: @Paul BONCAR
Yes .. I want to send the data to the back end by using the fetch() method .. so that I need to add something to body and headers properties ..